# How to keep DIV stretched to the bottom of the webpage with height 100% and overflow:auto using CSS only?

Tags: javascript, css, html, height

Salam all,

I have an HTML page with two sections, header and content, the header height is known and fixed, and the content height should fullfill the rest area of the webpage. While the content section fills the rest area of the webpage it should show a scrollbar if the contents are greater than the height of the webpage ( I don't want to see a webpage scrollbar, only content DIV scrollbar).

I have done this already (I've got the results that I want) using Javascript,

My question is : can I make the same behaviour using CSS?

Here is the code:

CSS file (site.css):

```
html, body 
{ 
height:100%; 
width:100%;     
padding:0;
margin:0; 
}

#header 
{
height:85px; 
width:100%; 
background-color : yellow;
}

#container
{
height: 100%;
width:auto; 
background-color : green;
padding:2px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#maindiv
{
height:100%;
width:100%; 
overflow:auto;
}
```

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body onresize="onheightchanged()" onload="onheightchanged()">
    <table id="header">
        <tr>
            <td>
            some headers <br /> 
            some headers <br /> 
            some headers <br /> 
            some headers <br /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="maindiv">
            contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
            contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
            contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
            contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
            contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
            contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getDocHeight() {
            var D = document;
            return Math.max(
                    Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
                    Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight));
        }


        function onheightchanged() {
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            var newheight = getDocHeight() - 90; // 90 = header height (85) + padding/margin (5)
            container.style.height = newheight + "px";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to set the container div absolute like this:

```
#container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 85px;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color : green;
}
```

You can also try to use `position: fixed`.

**Edit**: Added my version of the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    html, body 
    { 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;     
    padding:0;
    margin:0; 
    }

    #header 
    {
    height:85px; 
    width:100%; 
    background-color : yellow;
    }

    #container {
       position: absolute;
       top: 85px;
       bottom: 50px;
       left: 200px;
       right: 30px;
       overflow: auto;
       background-color : green;
    }

    #maindiv
    {
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
    overflow:auto;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<table id="header">
<tr>
       <td>
        some headers <br /> 
        some headers <br /> 
        some headers <br /> 
        some headers <br /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="container">
    <div id="maindiv">
        contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
        contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
        contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
        contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
        contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
        contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />contents <br />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, this solution worked perfectly for IE and Opera, Chrome also is fine with it, but FF 6.0.2 still showing a webpage scrollbar when I resize the page.

Comment: Strange, that works fine in my FF 6.0. The scrollbar is coming from the container. You can test it by tuning the left-, right-, and -bottom-positions so that container does not touch page borders. It should show better how the page behaves.

Comment: I did with no luck, the DIV height does not refresh automatically when you resize the page, you need to press F5 to have the correct behaviour, any clue?

Comment: Did you remember to remove all javascript-stuff from the page?

Comment: Sure I did, since the first test for your solution.

Comment: I have removed the event caller from the body tag, but I didn't remove the functions itself from the javascript section "one of the functions name was onload", now I have removed the whole script section and it's working fine, thank you for your help and support.

Answer (score 1):

Use **overflow-y:hidden;** in which produce scroll in that css.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:auto` doesn't work with percentage based height. What you can do is also set the height of `#maindiv` in the `onHeightChanged()` function after which `overflow:auto` should work.

Comment: You are referring me to javascript again, I have got the result that I want using javascript, I want it only using CSS.